# In a moving bus will the ball fall behind me when tossed?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

Using Newton's law I have to find whether in a moving bus will the ball fall behind me when tossed in air or will come to me only or will fall in front of me. In fact there are two cases;

1- Bus moving with constant speed

2- Bus moving with an acceleration of 1 m/s^2.

How do I proceed in each case?

Comment: *How do I proceed in each case?* Perhaps by using the kinematics equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Condition-A --- when bus is moving with a constant speed**

> When bus is moving with a constant velocity and you are standing in the bus your and the ball you are holding are moving with the same velocity as the bus, so when you throw the ball upward it maintain's the same forward velocity as before throwing and it land's back to the place were it was thrown from.

**Condition-B --- when the bus is moving with the acceleration of $1m/s^2$**

> when the bus is moving with a acceleration of $1m/s^2$ so are you and everything which is in contact with the bus. So the ball is also moving with an acceleration of $1m/s^2$, but as soon as you throw the ball upwards it loses contact with anything on the bus and so it stops accelerating and start's moving with a constant velocity which it had at the moment when it left the contact with the bus that is your hand, but you are still accelerating as you are still in contact with the bus so you will move forward and the ball will fall behind you as it stopped accelerating and so it will it is at lower velocity as compared to you

**Calculation for case B**

let us assume that the bus was moving with a velocity $v$ when you threw the ball
so the ball is now moving with a constant velocity $v$ but the bus and so you are still accelerating so now

you velocity when you threw the ball was also v but after time $t$ you would have travelled a distance $x$ and $x$ is according to this equation

$x = ut + \frac{1}{2}at^2$
in your case it will be equla to $x = vt + \frac{t^2}{2}$ as acceleration $a = 1m/s^2$ but the ball would traveled a distance only equal to $y = vt$ so it will fall at a distance $x-y$ behind you

Hope you got the answer you were expecting